# Angular 8 - Autorefresh directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I use a directive to restrict access to certain menus based on roles. This part works very well but I can not refresh this directive, indeed an administrator to choose to put it in user view, although these rights changes the directive is not re-executed. 
It's this function `this.permissionsService.hasPermission` that will return a different result.
How to do ?

```
<button mat-button *appHasAccess="['value1-1::value1-2']">Admin</button>
```

The directive

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.applyPermission();
  }

  private applyPermission(): void {
    this.permissionsService.hasPermission(this.appHasAccess).then((hasAccess: boolean) => {
      if (hasAccess) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
    }).catch(reason => {
      console.error(reason);
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not check the persision in ngOnInit -this only execute when the component take in the scene, aka if you has *ngIf or is in a component- use a setter in input like

```
@Input() set appHasAccess(value)
  {
    this.applyPermission(value)
  }
  private applyPermission(appHasAccess): void {
    this.permissionService.hasPermission(appHasAccess).then((hasAccess: boolean) => {
      if (hasAccess) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      }
    }).catch(reason => {
      console.error(reason);
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    });
  }
```

NOTE: I don't save the result of input in `this.appHasAccess` because it's not necesary in the working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkimth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't exactly what i'm looking for. In you case you change the value in the directive (fool to fool2) except that for me this value remains the same (admin or moderator) and it is the function hasPermission which does not return the same value according to the context.

Comment: If you want that "something change" you need say to Angular that some change. I'll use the "input" because i feel that is "the natural" way to do it. an ugly work around is enclosed all in a div with a *ngIf="variable" and make `this.variable=false;setTimeout(()=>{this.variable=true})`. When we make the variable false, remove form DOM, and when make the variable true execute again the ngOnInit. The setTimeout it's necesary to give Angular time to remove from the DOM